# Need a book about complex hermitian matrix and special unitary matrices and their optimization in numerical problems

Tags: group-theory, quadratic-forms, unitary-matrices, hermitian-matrices

I am studying about tomographic interferometric sar polarimetry and i don't have enough knowledge about complex hermitian matrix , special unitary groups, their quadratic forms and  numerical optimization based on these kind of matrices and forms in linear algebra. Is there some book or books  to start learning these topics for my lecture???
Thanks